# Getting a tooltip for any option in listview

Tags: javascript, jsp, tooltip

I have an interface with a listview of various options e.g 1)Asian 2) Euorpian 3)...... this listview is populated by calling JSP script that accesses this data (i.e. all 3 or more options) from database. I want to have a small popup window (like any help window) to be displayed when I move mouse over( onmousemove function) any option. e.g when i put mouse over Asian then a small help sort of window display Indians,chinese,thai...etc. This data Indians, chinese.... comes again by calling a jsp file since the related information is stored in database. Hence all options of listview will have different information which is dynamically changing from the database.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ready made javascript libraries out there that do exactly this, just google for "javascript tooltip" or "jquery tooltip".

If you don't want any bloat what so ever I suggest using jquery and simply creating the tooltip on the fly.

Eg.

```
$("select > option").hover(function( {
  pos = $(this).position();
  $(this).before($("<div>").css({position: absolute,left: pos.left,top: position.top}).text("Your Text"));
});
```

Note that this is just a very bare basic example, you'll still want to think about offset and consider that the parent element might offset the positioning as well. You could make the link itself relatively positioned and skip the position detection all together.

Also note that I don't think the hover event will trigger in every browser, as I don't think the listView option node does not have any events attached to it by design. You should consider an alternative flow or using a javascript library to show custom listView elements which will allow you to attach events to the option nodes. Here are some you can use:

http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#9

Anyway this should give you something to get started with.

Comment: . Thanks a lot for the tips... i looked on web and found lot of tooltip tutorials and information. Actually I have never used jquery before and I am more comfortable with javascript. So I have few tutorials on javascript tooltip. I want to ask that is it possible to call a tooltip function on onmousemove function. Since on mouse move i want to send the location of the selected item to a JSP file which will bring interested data back and that data I want to display as a text of tooltip. Thanks once again.. Kindly let me know if you need more details of the problem....

Comment: .. Actually i have given a bit more details in the asked question...I know the tooltip.js and tooltip.css files but the only concern is how to call the jsp file. Can you give some more information or point to some other good sources. Thanks

Comment: Look into javascript and ajax queries. I seriously suggest you give jquery a try, it automates a LOT of the process and is very well documented. Stackoverflow uses it too. To get data from an external service (such as your jsp) you would do something along the lines of $.get("file.jsp",function(response) { alert(response) });. As for onmousemove, you can simply create a function that is triggered every 100 ms that records the mouse position (easy with jquery). You might want to consider opening a new "question" on stackoverflow though, getting off topic.